# How to use roles?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, user-roles

```
login = async (creds: UserFormValues) => {
        try {
            const user = await agent.Account.login(creds);
            store.commonStore.setToken(user.token);
            runInAction(() => this.user = user);
            history.push('/activities');
            store.modalStore.closeModal();
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

I have this "login" that I want to edit it to make it with roles. Like:

```
login = async (creds: UserFormValues) => {
        try {
            const user = await agent.Account.login(creds);
            store.commonStore.setToken(user.token);
            runInAction(() => this.user = user);
            if(user.role = "admin"){
                history.push('/activities');
            }
            else{
                history.push('/home');
            }
            store.modalStore.closeModal();
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

But I get the warning

> Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment  no-cond-assign

and still the platform runs but it ignores the if statement. How can I make a conditional expression about this(If you can also show me the code about it)? Also I have 5 roles which should go all on different pages.

```
login = async (creds: UserFormValues) => {
            try {
                const user = await agent.Account.login(creds);
                store.commonStore.setToken(user.token);
                runInAction(() => this.user = user);
                if(user.role === "admin"){
                    history.push('/activities');
                }
                else{
                    history.push('/home');
                }
                store.modalStore.closeModal();
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        }
```

This is the updated code, when I login as admin it redirects me to home and not into activities, like the if doesn't exist.

Comment: There is a bug in `login`.  Your `if` statement needs the equality operator, not the assignment operator.  `if (user.role === "admin")` not `if(user.role = "admin")`.

Comment: Thank you, that got solved but now I'm running into another bug. System ignores the if statement and moves right to the else. Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: If you have resolved that typo, then could you please update the code in this question to the latest code that isn't working?

Comment: I updated the code, if you can check it out.

Comment: Ok, here's what you should do: below `runInAction` I want you to write `console.log(user.role)` and see what that returns.  Then look at `this.user` in log.  Then look at `user.role === "admin"` in log.  Likely the `if` isn't ignored, just you are not meeting the condition.

Comment: In whatever place I put console.log around here it shows blank on console nothing else.

Comment: Ok, then that would be the source of the issue.  If `user.role` returns empty on a `console.log` then there's no way your `if` condition would evaluate to true.